# The code passed is incorrect or expired passport-github

Tags: passport.js

I am using passport-github the node module to connect to github. I can access the github authorize page and after clicking to authorize I only get the error "The code passed is incorrect or expired". I've tried updating my github secret code and revoking all tokens and trying again however it still does not work.

I took the passport facebook example and simply changed it for github:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook

Comment: Did you figure it out? Im experiencing the same issue,  the documentation suggests to start over the oauth process.

Comment: No, I believe I switched from using passport to going through the full github oauth flow as seen here: https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/